# Java: Can't read more than one line from a text file

Tags: java

I am reading a text file with 6 integers each separated by a colon. I have very carefully checked for extraneous whitespace or characters. I think the input file is clean.

**Input Data**

```
101:102:103:104:105:106
360:350:370:370:350:360
360:350:370:370:350:360
```

I am having trouble reading past the first line. I can only get it to work if I remove all lines but the first line.

If I put more than one line of integers I get an error.

> Exception in thread "main"java.lan
>   ".NumberFormatException: For input string: "105

**Code** (I have used i<1 in the outer loop to prevent it from trying to read more, or else I get other errors...I'm trying to keep this simple.)

```
private void start()
{
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<seatArray[0].length; j++)
            {
                seatArray[i][j] = "?";
                scan.useDelimiter(":|\n");
                priceArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
                System.out.print("i="+i+" j="+j+" elem="+priceArray[i][j]+" ");
            }
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Use `scan.useDelimiter(":|\\n")` or `scan.useDelimiter(":|\\r\\n")`, the latter if on Windows.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. With your idea my original code (the code without using trim method  Scary Wombat suggested) worked.I clearly have some gaps in my understanding (but I'm a beginner).

Comment: No worries, glad we could help you!

Comment: I put a question that either of you might answer below SW's answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to trim the value as it includes the CR-LF

```
Integer.parseInt(scan.next().trim ());
```

Comment: That worked! But I don't understand the line of code. I will try to figure it out but if you care to explain it I will read with great interest. Thanks! I will also try what Tim B. said.

Comment: @quietstorm The Wombat's approach is to remove all whitespace from both sides of each line of your file.  This solves the problem you were having.

Comment: I have actually simplified it as it is already a String.  `trim` does *Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.*  If @TimBiegeleisen method works I would go for that as it is cleaner

Comment: I have done a little more thinking and looked at some other posts. I would like to ask two things: 1. How does my file have whitespace after the first line when I can't find it? If I open the file and scroll with the right arrow it goes right to the second line. 2. What is the significance or purpose of the extra slashes in Tim's idea (extra compared to other examples I can find)?

Comment: 1) Just because you can't _see_ it doesn't mean it is not there.  Line breaks, which tell your editor to start a new line, are a form of whitespace. 2) You need to escape the backslash in Java, hence two backslahses are needed.

Comment: @quietstorm fixed.